# orderBy, first one should be the oldest, the remaining newest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, filter, angularjs-filter

I am trying to sort my comments. I want the *last* comment to be the *first* one, and the remaining should be ordered by the `id`.

The below is sorting them by the `id`, but I need to put the last comment on top.

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments | orderBy:'-id'"></div>
```

If we have the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` the output should be `4, 1, 2, 3`. **note that this is not in chronological order**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is the output I am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10979/

Comment: I do not want it to be in chronological order. I updated the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

(Answer rewritten now I understand the question).

You'll need to use a custom sorting function.

```
max_comment_id = comments.reduce(function(p,c){ return Math.max(p,c.id)},0);

comments.sort(function(a,b){ 
    if (a.id == max_comment_id){return -1};
    if (b.id == max_comment_id){return 1};
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10982/)

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I added an example

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two div:-

Assuming data:-

```
$scope.comments = [
        {id: 1, comment: '1'},
        {id: 2, comment: '2'},
        {id: 3, comment: '3'},
        {id: 4, comment: '4'}
    ]

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments|orderBy:'-id'|limitTo:1">
        {{comment.comment}}
    </div>
        <div ng-repeat="comment in comments | orderBy:'id'|limitTo:comments.length-1">{{comment.comment}}</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLm5pmma/)

This solution may not be perfect but it can work for you.